# Python semantics of returning in a try block

Tags: python, try-catch, semantics

I have the following block in my code:

```
folder = 'validname2'
try:
    if folder == 'validname1':
        os.chdir('validname1')
        return functionRelevantToThisFolder()
    else
        if folder == 'validname2':
            os.chdir('validname2')
        elif folder == 'validname3':
            os.chdir('validname3')
        print("right before correct function call")
        return functionRelevantToTheseFolders()
except OSError as e:
    return "error message string"

def functionRelevantToTheseFolders():
    return "should say this"
```

The print before the second return is called. However, the return value is always "error message string".

It seems how I think about how this block should be ran differs from how Python has interpreted it. How should I restructure my code so that it matches how Python interprets this block?

Comment: There is most likely an error being raised in `functionRelevantToTheseFolders()`. Take a look inside the code for that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is simply that `functionRelevantToTheseFolders()` is raising `OSError` which is then catched by your except block, thus returning the 'error message string' instead.

To fix this problem and get the correct return value, figure out why `functionRelevantToTheseFolders()` is raising the exception in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the solved follow-up question that was generating the error http://stackoverflow.com/q/18855932/854854