# 'file not found' error when running local binary with Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a Python program to call a local binary with Popen to capture its output. I change directories to it with `os.chdir` and I have verified the file is there. However, the following code raises a 'file not found' exception.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Is there something special I have to do with running programs from directories not in my $PATH? Thanks in advance.

```
try:
    os.chdir('/home/me')
    p = sub.Popen(['./exec', '--arg', 'arg1'], cwd=os.getcwd(), stdout=sub.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
    print("done")
except OSError as e:
    print("error %s" % e.strerror)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note [this section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) of the docs (emphasis mine):

> If cwd is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to
>   cwd before it is executed. **Note that this directory is not considered
>   when searching the executable, so you can’t specify the program’s path
>   relative to cwd**.

Try using an absolute path with `Popen`.

```
p = sub.Popen(['/home/me/exec', '--arg', 'arg1'], stdout=sub.PIPE)
```

Answer (score -1):

To run a program from your $PATH, simply pass `shell=True` to Popen.

EDIT:

As well, as the OP asked, this works to run a program from the current directory.

Comment: This is explicitly discouraged in the docs, due to it creating unnecessary security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Sure. But this is what the OP wanted anyway, and most times won't be an issue.

Comment: I think you're mistaken - read the question again they have asked about running a program _is not_ under the $PATH, and you have answered about programs that _are_ in the $PATH.  Regardless, `$PATH` resolution is properly done by passing in a path using the `env` kwarg to Popen, _not_ by using `shell=True`.

Comment: The OP wanted to run a program from the current directory. `shell=true` does that, and also allows you to run from your $PATH. I've edited it to clarify.

Comment: -1 because `shell=True` may do that, but it is not the correct way to do that.